# GetData() does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlcommand

So I was trying follow along some asp.net tutorials on filling a Gridview with ajax.

On Microsoft's msdn example it has

```
DataSet ds = GetData(queryString);
```

which I found here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx

they are including

```
 <%@ import namespace="System.Data" %>
 <%@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
```

and my C# codebehind already has

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
```

On this example here he is using GetData() as well.
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView---Add-Edit-Update-Delete-and-Paging-the-AJAX-way.aspx

```
GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But anyway I am getting the error

```
 GetData() does not exist in the current context
```

when  I try it in my C# codebehind

```
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(command);
        AddressContactSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
        AddressContactSource.SelectCommand = command;

        DataSet ds= new DataSet;
        ds= GetData(sql);
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: `GetData` is jus a placeholder for the method that returns the `DataSet`.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand, it looked like a legitimate method in both examples.  What would you replace it?

Comment: Have a look at the first link that you've provided. There is an example of `GetData`. It's useful to implement such a method since you often need to get the data from different places. In your case you need it from `Page_Load`(`if(!IsPostBack)` and from other events where you need to databind the grid again(f.e. sorting,paging,updating,deleting):

Answer (score 4):

A GetData() method could be

```
  DataSet GetData(String queryString)
{

// Retrieve the connection string stored in the Web.config file.
String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthWindConnectionString"].ConnectionString;      

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

try
{
  // Connect to the database and run the query.
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);        
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

  // Fill the DataSet.
  adapter.Fill(ds);

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

  // The connection failed. Display an error message.
  Message.Text = "Unable to connect to the database.";

}

return ds;

}
```

Its standard procedure:
1 You provide the sql queryString to the function
2 connect to your database
3 create and fill a DataSet with the result of the query and return the DataSet. Then assign the DataSet to the DataSource.
You have to implement functions like GetData(yourQueryString) yourself.
As connection string you take the string to your database (here are some examples: [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)).

(Note: The above code example GetData() is just copied from the link you provided.)